# CarrierWave multiple file types validation with single uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

How to validate the extension of uploaded file when using single uploader for multiple file type?

I am using the single model namely Asset containing the attribute file. Uploader is mounted on file attribute. Asset model having one more attribute called feature_id. feature_id refers to features like video, audio, etc.

So, how should I validate the file type with multiple extension whitelist depending upon feature_id value?

Using ruby 1.9 and rails 3.2.11

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you thought about creating a whitelist model that belongs to the feature. within the file model you can scope the whitelist and include this into your uploader as the allowed criteria.

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/722274/kobaltz Thanks for your time. But I didn't get you, How do I use this with extension_white_list method?

Comment: It's much better to use different uploaders for that task, btw.

Comment: But how can I do that for with single model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the exact same use case:

In **Asset.rb**
Validate the format of the filename

```
validates :asset_file,
                 format:{
                    with: %r{\.(pdf|doc|png)$}i, message: "Wrong file format"
                        }
```

Use a regular expression to test the file name:

Here you can play with the regex:
http://rubular.com/r/Z3roRDDXAf

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @mholubowski  for your time. But I have multiple group of file extensions depending upon feature for which the upload is made. Do you mean to write a separate validates for each group with proc or lambda?

Comment: For time being, this is the only available working solution. But carrier wave should provide a way to do this. +1 for you unique efforts.

Comment: Rails gives a security warning: `The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?`

Answer (score 6):

Although the answer has been accepted but I've got a better way for this. Try this code.

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def extension_white_list
    if model.feature_id == 1
      %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
    elsif model.feature_id == 2
      %w(pdf doc docx xls xlsx)
    elsif model.feature_id == 3
      %w(mp3 wav wma ogg)
    end
  end
end
```

`feature_id == 1` means you want to allow just picture uploads, `feature_id == 2` means that only documents will be allowed to be uploaded and `feature_id == 3` will allow you to upload only audio files.

Hopefully it answers the question. You can add more checks for other types of files.

Comment: Quick ques, how does MyUploader know what feature_id is>

Comment: I mistaken this line of your question " Asset model having one more attribute called feature_id". I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry i wasn't the one that asked the question, i was just wondering how featured_id gets to MyUploader?

Answer (score 5):

Define your white list in your uploader as shown in the docs for carrierwave.

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks again but this time I am using the single uploader to upload multiple file types. I mean, single model will hold the video, audio and images depending upon the feature_id value. so how can I have multiple version of white_list for each feature_id?